# Why is Libclang unable to get definition of a function defined in a header file?

Tags: python, c++, parsing, clang, libclang

I am using LibClang to list down all function calls and their corresponding definition. 
Following is the python script to do so:

```
def traverse(node):
   if node.kind == CALL_EXPR:
       print(node.displayname, node.get_defintion()) 
   for c in node.get_children():
       traverse(c)
```

Following is the cpp code I run this on:

```
#include<math.h> 
int main()
{
   float n = sqrt(3.0);
}
```

Now, for the CXcursor referring to sqrt, I get the output sqrt , None

Can somebody explain why is it not able to find the definition of the function?

Comment: Note: the function is declared in the header file but not defined in the header file. Is there a node.get_declaration function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your libclang parsing method (whichever you use) with the `-I path/to/header/directory` argument